# CPLEX Error 1001 Out of memory

Tags: cplex, ilog

I was trying to solve an IMP with CPLEX. It throws an exception "CPLEX Error 1001: Out of memory" when I am building the model. The model contains around 2200000 line.    I am  getting this error while optimizing after using CPXmipopt.

how I can sort it out, note that when I check the memory form task manager, I found some unused memory.

Answer (score 2):

Have you entered a bigger value for the workMem parameter?
the default is 512 kbs
if You are using c++ you can add more memory to cplex by using

```
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::WorkMem ,2000.0);
```

(that adds 2Mbs of memory)
You can also try storing the Node tree on your harddrive using

```
cplex.setParam(IloCplex::WorkDir ,"c:/cplex/");
        cplex.setParam(IloCplex::NodeFileInd ,2);
```

/Buxley