# CPLEX out of memory, but reported tree size exceeds RAM; how to set TreLim?

Tags: memory, cplex

I'm solving a large set of MIP instances with CPLEX Concert in C++.  I've imposed a time limit on CPLEX for each instance (by setting the parameter TiLim), but some instances terminate when they run out of memory.  Here are the last several lines of output from such an instance:

```
 8734238 3080224      431.8614    36      470.0000      429.0000 3.88e+008    8.72%
 8752674 3084391        cutoff            470.0000      429.0000 3.89e+008    8.72%
Elapsed time = 59713.88 sec. (5451069.58 ticks, tree = 73513.33 MB, solutions = 6)
Nodefile size = 73384.21 MB (49191.99 MB after compression)
 8770964 3089127      429.9550    82      470.0000      429.0000 3.90e+008    8.72%
 8787928 3092972      442.7316    31      470.0000      429.0000 3.91e+008    8.72%
 8809081 3099887      429.4993    68      470.0000      429.0000 3.92e+008    8.72%
 8829373 3104804        cutoff            470.0000      429.0000 3.93e+008    8.72%

There may be further error information in the clone logs.

Cover cuts applied:  24
Implied bound cuts applied:  2
Flow cuts applied:  6
Mixed integer rounding cuts applied:  9
Zero-half cuts applied:  44
Gomory fractional cuts applied:  5

Root node processing (before b&c):
  Real time             =    7.19 sec. (744.51 ticks)
Parallel b&c, 8 threads:
  Real time             = 60536.50 sec. (5522542.15 ticks)
  Sync time (average)   =    0.00 sec.
  Wait time (average)   =    0.00 sec.
                          ------------
Total (root+branch&cut) = 60543.69 sec. (5523286.67 ticks)
```

The computer has 32 GB RAM, but the reported tree file size (71 GB, 48 GB after compression) exceeds that.  What does the tree file size reported by CPLEX mean, and how is it related to the available memory?  I would like to set the parameter TreLim to a value that prevents the out-of-memory error, but it's not clear to me what actually limits the size of the tree.

By the way, I have not stored the tree on the hard drive using the answer at [CPLEX Error 1001 Out of memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467038/cplex-error-1001-out-of-memory).  I'm not concerned with getting an optimal solution to each instance;  I just need a way to impose uniform limits of time or memory on each instance, such that once an instance has exceeded its limits, CPLEX can move on to the next instance.

Answer (score 0):

According to the CPLEX user manual, "[using nodefiles] entails only a very small increase in runtime".

You can use node files AND impose a time limit on your instances. Unless you run out of hard drive space, you should reach your time limit before getting a memory error.